# Como usar data de un router en un bucle for?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, bucle-for, data

tengo el siguiente problema:

```js
controller.matchCv = (req, res) => {
    req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
        conn.query('SELECT * FROM oferta', (err, oferta) => {
            if (err) {
                res.json(err);
            }
            res.render('match_cv', {
                data: oferta
            });
        });
    });
};

for(var i=0; i <=data.lenght; i++){ 
    var tablas= "tabla"+i;
            const element = document.getElementById(tablas);
            element.remove(); 
        }
```

necesito usar el data que obtengo de mi tabla "oferta" de la primera funcion, en el bucle for que esta abajo para ejecutar la funcion segun el valor de data.lenght.

si la ejecuto asi me dice que data esta undefined.

Comment: en que momento ejecutas el código `matchCv` y en que momento usas el código de abajo? no es muy clara la pregunta... por favor aclara e incluye mas detalles

Comment: haz lo que dice Pipe y en cuanto a tu pregunta, por como funciona js primero se ejecuta el bucle y despues el getConnection, esto es asi porque getConnection es asincrono y el bucle sincrono, investiga sobre asincronismo en js